# How to align two text boxes on same line with CSS

Tags: c#, css, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have two text boxes that by default, use "display: block;" style.  I want to keep the label above the first textbox, but I want the second textbox to be shown just to the right of the first text box.

Here is my view:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DescriptiveSize, "Descriptive Size")
    @*2014-04-11: Issue #93*@
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.DescriptiveSize, null, new { @class = "form-control", maxlength = "10",style = "width:25%;" })
    @Html.DropDownList("UomList", ViewData["UomList"] as SelectListItem[], new { @class = "form-control",style = "width:25%;" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DescriptiveSize)
</div>
```

Here is how it looks:

[image: display]

**EDIT:** And here is the HTML:
[image: HTML]

Comment: You can try floating both the input and textbox element to the left, and don't forget to clear the float in the parent container `.form-group`. Also, you should try including a HTML output so we know how your final markup looks like.

Comment: Use `display: inline-block`. It's supported by most browsers (IE anyone?) and should to the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a "float: left" property to your two textboxes. It makes it align on same line.

**HTML**

```
ABC<br />
<div id="textbox1"></div>
<div id="textbox2"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
#textbox1, #textbox2 {
    display: block;
    float: left;    
    width: 100px;    
    height: 100px;    
}

#textbox1 {
    background-color: red;
}

#textbox2 {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

See [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/blck/H499e/)

Comment: This gets the textboxes on the same line, but the Label "Descriptive Size" is now to the right of the second textbox.  It should be on the line above.

Comment: You can add a "<br />" tag before the first textbox, it makes a new line after your label.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `display: inline` or `display: inline-block` to the INPUT and SELECT elements:

**HTML**

```
<form class="selectSize">
    <label>Size</label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Small"/>
    <select>
        <option>Select..</option>
        <option>Size 1</option>
        <option>Size 2</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

**CSS**

```
.selectSize label,
.selectSize input,
.selectSize select {
    display: block;
}

.selectSize input,
.selectSize select {
    display: inline;
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Bg8EQ/)